# Check embedded fonts in pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Please, I want to know which fonts extracted from pdf is embedded or not, how can I do this using PDFBox?

Answer (score 3):

In PDFBox2, you would get the fonts and their embedded-status like this:

```
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
Iterator<COSName> ite = resources.getFontNames();
while (ite.hasNext()) {
    COSName name = ite.next();
    PDFont font = resources.getFont(name);
    boolean isEmbedded = font.isEmbedded();
    // ... do something with the results ...
}
```

I found no way, though, to find out which characters of the font are embedded, and which are not.

Comment: You merely inspect the immediate resources of the pages, not the resources of xobjects shown on the pages. In particular n-up documents often have all interesting content in xobjects.

Answer (score 2):

May be you find an answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828161/pdfbox-embedded-ttf-fonts-not-working)

or

To get all fonts, you have to iterate through pdf pages and extract font as below:

```
PDDocument  doc = PDDocument.load("C:/test.pdf");
List<PDPage> pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for(PDPage page:pages){
    Map<String,PDFont> pageFonts=page.getResources().getFonts();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is not the answer i need,
I want to check if the font is empedded or not embedded in pdf??