# Group revision elements for signed PDFs with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Based on my previous question [Fill out field for pdf revision when signing with PDFbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997537/fill-out-field-for-pdf-revision-when-signing-with-pdfbox/75003497#75003497) I was able to fill out the PDF field with a valid signature:

[image]

When looking at a signed document from AdobeSign they managed to group the fields like:

[image]

I am not able to analyse the created document von Adobe since they locked it at the end with a password. Is this to make sure nobody is able to edit the forms after the signature (I know that the signature is not valid anymore after somebody did it, but it reduces the risk of a user by accidentally writing into the field.

**Update:**

setting two signatures works and it will set the form fields in. But only for the Field 2, not the Field 1 from the first signature. see: https://file.io/cvHSBqRzXPyH

[image]

Comment: How about setting the fields to readonly by calling `setReadOnly(true)`? IIRC you can't do another certification signature.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it is possible to fill + sign a second time without breaking anything, see the update. I was just wondering why the steps are in another order an in adobe (there they sign the revision and THEN filled the forms).

Comment: field 1 (`23 0 obj`) was added at the same time as the first signature. Field 2 (`24 0 obj`) was added later, you can see this with NOTEPAD++. Thus field 1 isn't an "after signature" change.

Comment: I just wanted to look into this but the shared files seems to be deleted...

Comment: @mkl I haven chosen the wrong provider, here you go: https://filebin.net/26gdmydj3hlbt86z

Comment: Before.pdf does not exactly match the origin of After.pdf but is at least similar. I'll take a look.